# HTTP request is a POST request, xxl-job parameter is GET, why execute

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Please give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
xxl-job log：
----------- xxl-job job execute start -----------
Param:url: http://172.18.0.155:8888/test
method: GET
data: content
----------- xxl-job job execute end(finish) -----------
----------- ReturnT:ReturnT [code=200, msg=null, content=null]
----------- xxl-job job callback finish.
```

My code only print log

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test1(){
        log.info("======================================test  xxl-job");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hidden bug in "httpJobHandler" : "setDoOutput(true)" causes "setRequestMethod("GET");" Invalidation forces assignment to "POST".

This issue has been fixed and pushed to the Github Master branch.

https://github.com/xuxueli/xxl-job/commit/17b416ca070d13ee567a4963592873eea80f3ef1

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely。Unexpectedly, it's you